# How can I create a dynamic path for my cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I have a problem with my path! I need a way to make my path dynamic. I have programmed a cli that works on my system but not on others, because the paths keep changing. I want to make it crossplatform capable. What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you at all!

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/TimothieMT/sweetStack

```
function absPath() {

    let result = ''

    const winPath1 = `${path.parse(process.cwd()).root}/Users/${process.env.USERNAME}/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/${name}/`
    const winPath2 = `${path.parse(process.cwd()).root}/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/${name}/`

    const linuxPath1 = `${path.parse(process.cwd()).root}/lib/node_modules/${name}/`
    const linuxPath2 = `${path.parse(process.cwd()).root}/home/${process.env.USERNAME}/.nvm/versions/node/${process.version}/lib/node_modules/${name}/`

    const macPath1 = `${path.parse(process.cwd()).root}/usr/local/lib/node_modules/${name}/`

    switch (process.platform) {
        case 'win32':
            if (fs.existsSync(winPath1)) {
                result = winPath1
            } else {
                result = winPath2
            }
            break;
        case 'linux':
            if (fs.existsSync(linuxPath1)) {
                result = linuxPath1
            } else {
                result = linuxPath2
            }
            break
        case 'darwin':
            return macPath1
        default: {
            console.log(chalk.red('your platform is not supported'))
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

I install my cli globally, and therefore I need to load my data. I want to load also from the global node_modules folder.

Comment: Perhaps someone else could chime in for Linux and Mac, but for Windows - you could try and read the path from the `PATH` system variable. This would let you know the path of `node.exe`, and, assuming that `node_modules` exists within the same directory, you'd get them as well. You could also prompt the user to enter the paths manually, and check if they're correct after the user enters them. If they are, save them in a config file, and read them from that config file the next time your `absPath()` is called (with checking whether they still exist on that path, etc).

Comment: thank you! have a second option to add path manually for the case path not found.